# Prove that $ (A \cup B)'\subset A' \cup B'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Prove that $ (A \cup B)'\subset A' \cup B'$

My attempt:

Suppose $p\in (A\cup B)'$, If $p\notin A'$.claim that  $p\in B'$. since $p\notin A'$ so there exist  $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $N_{\epsilon_0}(p)\cap A \subset \{p\}$.

Now for any $\epsilon >0$ ,let $r= \min \{\epsilon,\epsilon_0\}$. Since $p \in (A \cup B)'$, $N_r(p)\cap A\subset \{p\}$. From the assumption that $p\in(A\cup B)'$, we deduce that $N_r(p)\cap(A\cup B)\ne\emptyset$, so $N_r(p)\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

It follow that $p$ is a limit point of $B$, so $p \in B'= (A\cup B)'$. This implies that $(A \cup B)'= B'$.

Finally $(A \cup B)'\subset  A' \cup B'$ which completes the proof.

Note : $N_r(p)$ denote the neighborhood of $p$ consisting of all $q$ such that $d(p,q)  <r$ and  $A'$ denote  the set of all derived points of $A$

Is this proof correct or not?

Comment: How do you know that $p \not \in A'$ implies $p \in B'$? I don't follow that step.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer im just claiming that $p$ can be belong $B'$

Comment: The proof looks good to me. The symbols for interiors and closures vary a lot so it's helpful to explain your notation, even if it's clear from the context like it is here. I follow that proof that if $p \notin A'$, then $p \in B'$ but I don't think $(A \cup B)' = B'$ is correct. Your proof seems to work without that though so it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: oks thanks !!@DanielApsley

Comment: @DanielApsley that must  be necssary that $(A \cup B)'= B'$  otherwise  we will not get the proof

Comment: You need to define your notation. What does $A'$ mean? And what does $N_r(p)$ mean?

Comment: @quid im sorry for that. that i have not mention the notation .....Here $N_r(p) $ denote neighborhood of $p$ conisting of all $q $such that $d(p,q) <r$ and $A'$ denote the set of all derived points of $A$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You could edit this into the post. There is a problem in the proof. It is not true that $p \notin A'$ implies that there is an $\epsilon$ such that  $N_{\epsilon}(p) \cap A$ is empty. You can only say it is a subset of $\{p\}$

Comment: Remark: The notion of "accumulation points" and derived set "$A'$" are pure topological concepts. That is, they can be defined without referencing to any metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify the picture, let us recall the definition of "derived
point" or "accumulation point". Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological
space. Let $A\subseteq X$. We say that $p\in X$ is an accumulation
of $A$ if for each neighborhood $U$ of $p$, $(U\setminus\{p\})\cap A\neq\emptyset.$
The set of all accumulation points of $A$ is denoted by $A'$.

Let $A,B\subseteq X$, we go to prove that $(A\cup B)'\subseteq A'\cup B'.$
Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exists $p\in(A\cup B)'\setminus(A'\cup B').$
Hence, $p\notin A'$ and $p\notin B'$. Choose an open neighborhood
$U$ of $p$ such that $U_{p}\cap A=\emptyset$, where $U_{p}:=U\setminus\{p\}$.
Choose open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $V_{p}\cap B=\emptyset$.
Let $W=U\cap V$, which is an open neighborhood of $p$. Observe that
$W_{p}\cap A\subseteq U_{p}\cap A=\emptyset$ and $W_{p}\cap B\subseteq V_{p}\cap B=\emptyset$.
Therefore, $W_{p}\cap(A\cup B)=(W_{p}\cap A)\cup(W_{p}\cap B)=\emptyset$,
which contradicts to the fact that $p\in(A\cup B)'.$